# Set selected attribute for single/multi selection with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

It seems that angular's behavior with respected to the selected attribute has changed back and forth with each major version. So I'm just looking for someone to tell me if this is achievable in the 1.5.x release using ng-options rather than ng-repeat.

What I'm trying to do:
Have angular create html like the following(so that it can be interpreted by a jquery plugin)

```
<select multiple="multiple"...>
<option value="abc123" label="Justin" selected="selected">Justin</option>
</select>
```

I've tried many variations of this

```
<select ms-multi-listbox multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" 
 id="ym" name="ym" ng-model="groupCtrl.memSelection" 
ng-options="mem as mem.displayName for mem in groupCtrl.selectableMembers track by mem.id">
```

with no luck.

the model looks like this:

```
groupCtrl.memSelection =["abc123"];//inbound from api as is selectableMembers
```

Here is a plunk I've been playing with (try changing the angular version for added confusion): [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWrzQLzDTPw85jRXZ6Bj)

Any ideas are welcome.. I mainly wanted to avoid ng-repeat because it has a lot of overhead in longer lists but obviously slow is better than not working so I'll use it until I learn how to do this with ng-options.

Thanks!

**edit:**
Here is a ng-repeat that achieves the result I want:

```
<option ng-repeat="mem in groupCtrl.selectableMembers" value="{{mem.id}}" label="{{mem.displayName}}" ng-selected="groupCtrl.memSelection.indexOf(mem.id)>=0">{{mem.displayName}}</option>
enter code here
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to set an attribute based on selection.  You'll need a custom directive for this.

Comment: yes, I want to set the 'selected' attribute on the options tag. Angular does this for you in some cases (and some versions) when your model is initialized to a value in the list.

Comment: Your plunker link is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression. [AngularJS API ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Your expression for `ng-options` can't work. Using `select as` and `track by` in the same expression evaluates `mem.id` to `mem.id.id`. Change the expression to

```
ng-options="mem as mem.displayName for mem in groupCtrl.selectableMembers track by mem.id"
```

And how you set the selected objects don't look right to me as well. You can not just set the id, you have to set the whole object as selected otherwise your `ng-options` expression evaluation will also fail. Therefore change your selection to (assuming selectable data is stored in `$scope.model` as it is in the plunk example).

```
$scope.memSelection = [$scope.model[0], $scope.model[1]]
```

I have updated the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hN0rPkEPV4OMo4Hxap1W) and it works for single and multi selection.

For more information read [AngularJS API ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: I think it works now except for 1.4 versions but only for single select (updated plunker link). I'm guessing that applying the attribute for multiselect is what isn't supported.