# How can i by default set all options selected in multi-select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am populating my multi-select dropdown from json object.

Here is my select dropdown

```
<select size="2" id="inst_all" style="width:200px;" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedCountries"
ng-options="sort.Institute as sort.Institute for sort in products | unique : 'Institute'">
</select>
```

I have tried with following jquery snippet , but it didnt worked.

```
<script>$('#inst_all option').prop('selected', true);</script>
```

How can i select all options be default ?

Comment: Where *exactly* do you run your script?  Could be that you're running it too soon, try wrapping it in doc.ready `$(() => { ..your code.. });`

Comment: Does this answer your question [set selected for multi selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196962/set-selected-attribute-for-single-multi-selection-with-ng-options)  or this  [use ng-option to set default value of select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element) (though that's for a singlevalue, looks like you set it on the `ng-model`)

Answer (score 0):

When using dynamic content from a `json` file/object you should always make sure the page is fully loaded before doing any actions on DOM elements.
Use `$( document ).ready(function() {`

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#inst_all option').prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="2" id="inst_all" style="width:200px;" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedCountries"
ng-options="sort.Institute as sort.Institute for sort in products | unique : 'Institute'">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```